# Creating Unsorted List in range 100,000 to 1000,000

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, random

I am looking to create a function that would return an unsorted list of 20 numbers in the range 100 to 1,000 (in thousands) and need not be unique. Further, I am looking for them to be multiples of 25.

In the next step, I am looking to sort them from smallest to largest. I am looking for help on how to insert the restrictions of max 20 random UNSORTED numbers divisible by 25:

```
def bookinventory(i, j):
    import random
    booknumber = [x for x in range(i, j)]
    random.shuffle(booknumber)
    print(booknumber)

def main():
    books = bookinventory(100000, 1000000)
    print(books)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you asking for how to make sure that the books are unsorted?

Comment: I think you would want to `return` and not `print` at the end of `bookinventory`

Comment: this code does provide random unsorted list but too many. looking to only get 20 random numbers divisible by 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit to 20 elements you can do:

```
booknumber = [random.randint(i, j) for _ in range(20)]
```

---

To take only 20 divisible-by-25 elements you can use [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
booknumber = random.choices([x for x in range(i, j+1) if x % 25 == 0], k=20)
```

This is for the general case where `i` and `j` are not known. If you know the numbers as in your example, you can use arithmetics to make things simpler:

```
booknumber = [random.randint(4000, 40000) * 25 for _ in range(20)]
```

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo - that works. Curious whether there is a way to generate a unsorted list without using random library ? Making sure I am not doing an overkill trying to use a library of functions meant for more complex problems.

Comment: not at all. `random` is a built-in library meant for all your random needs. Doesn't have to be complex. You will be doing an overkill trying to implement something that already has a library for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will create 20 unique numbers between 100,000 and 1,000,000 divisible by 25:

```
def bookinventory(i, j):
    import random
    booknumbers = list(range(i, j + 1, 25))
    return sorted([random.choice(booknumbers) for _ in range(20)])

def main():
    books = bookinventory(100000, 1000000)
    sorted_books = sorted(books)
    print(sorted_books)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main component of this is:

```
sorted([random.choice(booknumbers) for _ in range(20)])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a unsorted list of 20 non-unique integers ranging from 100,000 to 1,000,000 that are divisible by 25.

```
b = [x * 25 for x in random.choices(range(4000, 40000), k = 20)]
```

You can change your code like this:

```
def bookinventory(i,j):
    import random
    booknumber = [x * 25 for x in random.choices(range(int(i/25), int(j/25)), k = 20)]
    print(booknumber)
    return booknumber

def main():
    books = bookinventory(100000,1000000)
    sorted_books = sorted(books)
    print(sorted_books)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a program to get your desired output

```
import random 
final_list = []
final_list_set = set(final_list)
final_list_set_len = len(final_list_set)
while final_list_set_len < 20:
    final_list_set = set(final_list)
    final_list_set_len = len(final_list_set)
    num = random.randint(100,1000)
    if (num%25 != 0):
        continue
    else:
        final_list.append(num)
        continue
final_list = list(final_list_set)
final_list.sort(reverse = False)
print("The list is",final_list)
print("The length of the list is",len(final_list))
```

**I added the last line in code so that you can verify the number of elements in the list.**
I hope this is useful :)